# RuntimeError when running script?

Tags: ruby

So I have found this RUBY script, which looks for all PNG images in sub folders and folders and converts PNG images using TinyPNG API but for some reason I get runtime error

> C:/Users/Vygantas/Desktop/tinypng.rb:14:in `': 
>   Usage: ./tinypng.rb C:/Users/Vygantas/Desktop/product C:/Users/Vygantas/Desktop/product(RuntimeError)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

#
# tinypng.rb — Placed into the public domain by Daniel Reese.
#

require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

# Set API key.
apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Verify arguments.
ARGV.length == 2 or fail("Usage: ./tinypng.rb C:\Users\Vygantas\Desktop\product C:\Users\Vygantas\Desktop\product*emphasized text*")
src = ARGV[0]
dst = ARGV[1]
File.exist?(src) or fail("Input folder does not exist: " + src)
File.exist?(dst) or fail("Output folder does not exist: " + dst)

# Optimize each image in the source folder.
Dir.chdir(src)
Dir.glob('*.png') do |png_file|
    puts "\nOptimizing #{png_file}"

    # Optimize and deflate both images.
    cmd = "curl -u api:#{apikey} --data-binary @#{png_file} 'https://api.tinypng.com/shrink'"
    puts cmd
    r = JSON.parse `#{cmd}`
    if r['error']
        puts "TinyPNG Error: #{r['message']} (#{r['error']})"
        exit(1)
    end
    url = r['output']['url']
    cmd = "curl '#{url}' -o #{dst}/#{png_file}"
    puts cmd
    `#{cmd}`
end
Dir.chdir("..")

puts 'Done'
```

Comment: I need whole error message and backtrace to debug this error.

Comment: @MarekLipka Of course you don’t need it. Take a precise look: it’s a script who prints it because an expectation on amount of arguments was not met :)

Comment: @mudasobwa You're right. Go ahead with an answer. :)

Comment: @Lipka, that's all I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might see in the code, line 14 (as printed on script execution):

```
ARGV.length == 2 or fail("Usage: ./tinypng.rb 
    C:\...\product C:\...\product*emphasized text*")
```

That said, a script requires two parameters to run. Let me guess: you did not pass two parameters. Those are btw *source* and *destination* folders.

Comment: If I change to

ARGV.length == 2 or fail("Usage: "./tinypng.rb", "/product",  "/product"")

I get: C:/Users/x/Desktop/tinypng.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, e
xpecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...age: "./tinypng.rb", "/product", "/product"")

Comment: You have to specify arguments to a script, you are not supposed to modify the script itself. Like this (in console): `./tinypng.rb C:/Users/Vygantas/Desktop/product C:/Users/Vygantas/Desktop/productModified`. **NB** Source and destination folder should likely differ.

Comment: I am an idiot!

Still, looks like it is broken :/

Optimizing textpicture.png
curl -u api:cfgibsPM-f_7ETa9jgv_WkONlpEGsU920 --data-binary @textpicture.png 'https://api.tinypng.
om/shrink'
C:/Users/Vygantas/Desktop/tinypng.rb:28:in ``': No such file or directory - cur
 -u api:cfgibsPM-f_7ETa9jgv_WkONlpEGsU920 --data-binary @textpicture.png 'https://api.tinypng.com/
hrink' (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Users/Vygantas/Desktop/tinypng.rb:28:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Users/Vygantas/Desktop/tinypng.rb:22:in `glob'
        from C:/Users/Vygantas/Desktop/tinypng.rb:22:in `<main>'

Comment: Install `curl` on the target machine? Whether it’s Ubuntu, run `sudo aptitude install curl`.

Comment: Now just says done and no files are outputed, anyway, thanks for help

Comment: Unfortunately from now on I can’t help you much: I have no clue about this tool in particular and tinypng in general.